# Decorator assignment

Tags: python, python-decorators

Suppose decorator

```
@app.callback(
    Output("plot_1", "figure"),
    [Input("checklist", "value"),
     Input("radio", "value")])
```

which is repeated in code several times. The only difference between the copies is different plot names.

How is it possible to assign that decorator to another decorator and use the latter?

```
@new_callback("plot_1")
```

Comment: `def new_callback(plot): return app.callback(Output(plot, ...), ...)` should do…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorator syntax is just a shortcut for function application; `app.callback` is just a function. Create a *new* function that calls it with fixed arguments.

```
def new_callback(plot):
    return app.callback(
          Output(plot, "figure"),
          [
              Input("checklist", "value"),
              Input("radio", "value")
          ]
    )
```

`app.callback` itself is not actually the decorator; it's a function that *returns* the decorator (i.e., the function that takes the function to be decorated as an argument).

```
@app.callback(...)
def foo():
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def foo():
    ...

foo = app.callback(...)(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a decorator in its own decorator and use arguments you pass in any of the sub-functions, like so:

```
def decorator_wrapper(arg1):

    # do something with arg1:
    print('Inside decorator_wrapper, arg1: ' + str(arg1))

    def decorator(function):

        print('Inside decorator, arg1: ' + str(arg1))

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            print('Inside wrapper, arg1: ' + str(arg1))

            # execute decorated function: 
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)

            return result

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@decorator_wrapper('a')
def MyFunction():

    print('This is my function')


MyFunction()
```

This will result in:

```
Inside decorator_wrapper, arg1: a
Inside decorator, arg1: a
Inside wrapper, arg1: a
This is my function
```

More here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-with-parameters-in-python/